# `Editable-Changable` Variable in a delete statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

think about this with me and tell me if it´s possible:

Lets say u have a simple delete statement like this one:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","inventarisdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if (!mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM BCD WHERE LastName='Griffin'");
{
echo "Succesfully Deleted <br/> ";
echo "<a href='Reports.php'>View Result</a>";
 }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This statement deletes everything in the table row that matches that given Lastname. Great! but now:

Lets say that Ur table gets updated a lot and ur adding names and U get more entries with the same LastName , but U don't want all of them Rows to get deleted with this LastName.

Is it possible to write the Delete statement in such a way that the variable for LastName is Editable or Changeable?
What I mean is for example: being able to Change LastName to Age for example or Any other variable I have in the table that I want to use instead to execute delete with, without having to do so in my php script, but simply from the app. page itself.

So the actions u would take with such a code would be navigating to the Delete tab in this app, Changing the variable u want to use to make ur search for delete with, through typing or a drop down list for example and eventually press delete for execute.

I'm thinking something like this for example:

```
 if (!mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM persons WHERE (variable)='<a href: Select2Delete.php>'");
```

And so I would be able to fill in the variable corresponding to my table collumns I want to search by to delete.

I have been looking @ checkboxes and auto increment and ways about doing this differently, but I want to know if this is possible first since I find it an easy way to make the script work compared to having to set up a table that first looks up the data and then add checkboxes with a delete button with a load of If Statements to execute a delete by selecting a box feel me?

Any advice, comment, remark is welcome! This is a Pure thought that I want to share and ask ur opinion about!

Thank you in advanced!
Cheers to this forum!

Comment: I would normally only delete by an id or other unique key after searching to find the id I am interested in to ensure that only the corrected row is deleted.

Comment: I think its the best and safest way as well ty :) I'm asking just for informing myself'sake :) to broaden my horizon on programming and whats and whys and hows ^^ Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, if you are linking the page from an html page.

```
<a href="deleterecord.php?column=age&value=20">Delete</a>
```

in php side

```
$query = "DELETE FROM table where ".$_GET['column']."=".$_GET['value'];
mysql_query($query, $con);
```

Please note that this method is not very safe, but you can achieve your solution by using this direction.

Comment: this idd looks like something I had in mind thnx! I'm gonna try this out!

Answer (score 0):

You should get used to IDs.
In almost every table that I create i have an Int column with a primary key and auto increment.
That way you will never get into the trouble of deleting multiple rows by accident.

If you still want to do it like that take a look at Architact's post.

Comment: Yes I am very aware of this thank you! I want to know if its possible and to see how it works so I can decide and determine for myself whats the best way to approach this situations and resolve them and why.

But again Idd ID's I agree are the best way from what i've researched so far :)
Nothing like auto increment to delete by ID number. plain simple :)

Just a lot of scripting to make that work :P

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be ID but you should have a unique key not for only these kind of updating, deleting stuff but also matching data in other tables or better select queries sometimes. Lastname is not a good choice for unique key as you also mentioned, there may be duplicates. You can create a string unique key for each record, like mary-bennett | mary-benett1 | mary-benett2 ...

However, if you are afraid of if a record is added when you are performing delete query, that will not happen. SQL won't response to someone else before completing your task.